# remove whitespace which are in between String in Mongodb

Tags: string, mongodb, trim

For this document: `{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "  Shyam   Lingam  " }`

**Expected:** while retrieving _id = 3 then result should come like below:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Shyam Lingam" }
```

**I tried this:** `db.collection.find({_id:3},{name:{$trim:{input:"$name"}}})`

`{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Shyam   Lingam" }`

but still whitespace between Shyam and Lingam is there which should not come.

Comment: Why is the space between Shyam and Lingam not expected to be removed?

Comment: hi @ray, yes it's not expected to be removed

Comment: Your title is very confusing. And how is `$trim` not working?

Comment: trim is working but it removing left and right whitespaces but i want to remove whitespaces betweem "Shyam" and "Lingam".

Comment: so the space in between should be removed or not??? Your expected behavior keep changing! You should [edit] your question with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query may look complex.

1. `$trim` - Trim the value of *1.1* at the beginning and end.

   1.1. `$reduce` - Transform array to string.

   1.1.1. `input` - Split `name` by space and filter the word which is not space.

   1.1.2. `initialValue` - Set the initial value as an empty string.

   1.1.3. `in` - With `$concat`, combine all the elements into a string with ' ' as the delimiter.

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: 3
},
{
  name: {
    $trim: {
      input: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                $split: [
                  "$name",
                  " "
                ]
              },
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  "$$this",
                  ""
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              " ",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ypKWWSFod09)

Comment: hi @Youg Shun, is there no specific operator to use to remove whitespace within the string like $trim? instead of using many operators to get this result, we can use only one operator which could give the same result

Comment: [`$trim`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/) only support for removing whitespace at the beginning and end. I think there is no any operator from MongoDB that supports your requirement. Thus, have to do some "dirty" works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it should be work

```
db.collection.update(
  { "_id": 3 },
  { "$set": { "name": { "$trim": { "input": "$name" } } } }
)
```

After update output is:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Shyam Lingam" }
```